# repeat background music after it ends cocos2dx?

Tags: android, audio, cocos2d-x

In my app for android, i want to play a music in the background throughout until the game quits. The sound is of length 1 min. What i want is that the sound to repeat automatically when the track ends. any idea?

**Update**
I figured out the solution myself. If someone else have the same problem, here is the solution
SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->playBackgroundMusic(std::string(music_file_name)),true);

The true in the end tells if the sound will loop or not.
True: sound will repeat once it has ended.
False: Will play just once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CocosDenshion should have a **loop** parameter that will handle this for you.

[See here for an example](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Chapter_6_-_How_to_Play_Music_and_Sound_Effect)

Make sure you use `PlayBackgroundMusic("file", true)` for music and `playEffect('file')` for sounds though; I seem to recall that `playBackgroundMusic` has the ability to stream an mp3 from disk (whereas effects have to be loaded into RAM first).

Answer (score 1):

You can copy paste the .mp3 or .wav file in the resource folder than add the file in project  than use this line as follows:

CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->playBackgroundMusic("background-music.wav", true);

and to play sound effect you copy paste the .mp3 file or .wav file in resource folder then add that to project and use this line as follows:

CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->playEffect("pew-pew.wav");

make sure you write(without the first ")

"#include "SimpleAudioEngine.h"

at the start of file

and include the corresponding libraries.

Regards,
Dushyant.